# does casting to a str decode a bitwise string

Tags: python, string, casting, binary-string

observe the following

```
signature = rsa.sign(str(message), private_key, 'SHA-1')
```

see how message is being casti to a str

would that decode a bit wise string?

why I ask.

the code snippet above is being used by the aws boto library which is using the rsa libary and I keep getting an error from the rsa library

```
 File "/Users/bullshit/Documents/softwareprojects/shofi/backend/virtualshofi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto/cloudfront/distribution.py", line 677, in _sign_string
    signature = rsa.sign(str(message), private_key, 'SHA-1')
  File "/Users/bullshit/Documents/softwareprojects/shofi/backend/virtualshofi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 337, in sign
    msg_hash = compute_hash(message, hash_method)
  File "/Users/bullshit/Documents/softwareprojects/shofi/backend/virtualshofi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py", line 439, in compute_hash
    assert hasattr(message, "read") and hasattr(message.read, "__call__")
AssertionError
```

The error is not important to the context of my question but its good for grounding. The reason why I am asking is also out of context

Thank you

Comment: If `message` is a `bytes` object, this will almost certainly do the wrong thing. If it's `bytes` in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding, then you want `message.decode()`; if it's `bytes` in some other encoding, you want `message.decode('<insert-encoding-name-here>')`.

Comment: What is a "bitwise string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) docs

> If neither *encoding* nor *errors* is given, `str(object)` returns `type(object).__str__(object)`, which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of *object*.

So `str(message)` is roughly equivalent to `message.__str__()`<sup>[1]</sup>. What it does depends entirely on the class of `message`. So you need to figure out the type of that message argument and look up its documentation.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I say "roughly equivalent". As noted in the docs, it's actually equivalent to `type(object).__str__(object)`. The difference is usually trivial in the course of normal Python programming, but it can make a difference if a function is assigned directly to an instance or if some object with a funny `__get__` is declared inside the class. Assuming you're using a relatively standard library, I doubt either of those is in play here.